# Pipilened vs table type return function in PL/SQL

Tags: function, optimization, plsql

What are the advantages and disadvantages of pipilened PL/SQL functions also compared with functions that are not pipilened and have return type of "Table" (collection of records). With examples of situations if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that with a pipelined function, your function could create unlimited/endless result sets. For example, the function could return the natural numbers or the Fibonacci sequence. When using it within a query, you could add `where rownum < 100` to limit the output to the length you actually need.

Another, practically more important difference is that if you are NOT using a `PIPELINED` table function, the complete result set must be computed before it is used.
This can matter extremely if computing the result is slow/costly.
Often, the user only wants to see the first N rows (which is why the `FIRST_ROWS` optimizer mode exists).
In other words, only `PIPELINED` table functions support `FIRST_ROWS` at all, as the results are computed only when needed.

Compare this to finding something on the internet: Most often, you find the interesting link on the first page of the result set and you're not interested in the millions of hits following.

Comment: That sounds logical :) @hvb